# If- else statement shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script to rotate a log file based on size leveraging the `logrotate.conf` utility.

```
#!/bin/bash 
FILENAME=/xyz/console.log  

    while :
    do  
        FILESIZE=$(du -h "$FILENAME")

        ####FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")

        if [[ $FILESIZE > 10K ]];
        then
            echo "$FILENAME is too large = $FILESIZE"
            echo "$(date ) is here"
            cd "/etc"
            $sudo logrotate -f logrotate.conf
            echo "$ Newer version of log file is created"
        else
            echo "Log limit is not reached"
        fi
    sleep 60s

done

exit 0
```

It is not printing `else` block ,even when the size is less than 10K. In all cases, it is executing the `if` block and rotating the logs even at 4.0K. Only when the log file is of zero bytes it is printing `else` part i.e.:

> Log limit is not reached

Comment: Why not use `stat` or `du` (without `-h`)? The problem is that `du` will bring the file name too, unless you use `cut -f 1`. The ideal is to get the value in bytes and compare.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `[[ > ]]` is doing a string comparison (essentially, alphabetical order) rather than numeric comparison. So, for example, `[[ 9 > 10 ]]` is true, because the character "9" comes after "1" in ASCII sorting order. But switching to numeric comparisons (with `(( > ))` or `[[ -gt ]]`) won't work either, because the "numbers" you're comparing have unit suffixes ("B" for byte, "K" for kilobyte, etc, so 500B is less than 1K) *and* the output from `du` also includes the filename, which'd need to be striped before comparing.

This is much too much work. Just use `stat` to get a pure numeric result, and do numeric comparison on that. Oh, and you should stick to lower- or mixed-case variable names, to avoid accidentally using one of the ones that has special meaning to the shell (e.g. `PATH`):

```
...
filesize=$(stat -f %z "$filename")
if (( filesize > 10240 )); then
...
```

Comment: I have tried various options as suggested and modified the code as

 while :
   
    do  
    FILESIZE=$(du  "$FILENAME")  

  #FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")

#FILESIZE=$( du -b "$FILENAME" | cut -f1)
 
        if (( $FILESIZE > 1000000 ));
        then
        echo "$FILENAME is too large = $FILESIZE"
        echo "$(date ) is here"
     cd "/etc"
  $sudo logrotate -f logrotate.conf
  echo "$ Newer version of log file is created"
        else
   echo "Log limit is not reached"
    fi
   sleep 60s

   the log file in question is 96185 bytes..still getting rotated

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharya Did you try the `stat` command I recommended? Also, have your script print the value of `FILESIZE` before checking it, so you can see what's actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

You are using string comparision. For example, if the file size is 2K, `2K > 10K` is true, because 2 comes alphabetically after 10.

Easiest solution would be to drop the `-h` option - which doesn't make much sense anyway, if you want to process the result further - and then use numerical comparision,

```
if (( FILESIZE > 10 ))
then

fi
```

Comment: I have tried various options as suggested and modified the code as

 while :
   
    do  
    FILESIZE=$(du  "$FILENAME")  

  #FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")

#FILESIZE=$( du -b "$FILENAME" | cut -f1)
 
        if (( $FILESIZE > 1000000 ));
        then
        echo "$FILENAME is too large = $FILESIZE"
        echo "$(date ) is here"
     cd "/etc"
  $sudo logrotate -f logrotate.conf
  echo "$ Newer version of log file is created"
        else
   echo "Log limit is not reached"
    fi
   sleep 60s

   the log file in question is 96185 bytes..still getting rotated

Comment: Post your modified code. Also, show the value of `FILESIZE`.